# Forwarding traffic from one VPS to another to utilize GCP's network and speedy connection

Tags: networking, ssh, openvpn, google-cloud-platform

I have a VPN currently hosted on a VPS far away. For this reason, I have a pretty slow connection. I hypothesize that if I have a VPS close to me, I could connect to the closer one, and use that to tunnel through the cloud provider network, reducing latency.

How would I configure two servers, Server A, and Server B, such that I connect to Server B using OpenVPN, and it forwards all the traffic to Server B? Would my public IP be Server A's or Server B's public IP address?

I am on the Google Cloud Platform.

Here's the idea as a drawing:

[image: the idea as a drawing]

Comment: Before investing too much time, review pricing for Google egress network traffic.  Google charges for network traffic: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing

Answer (score 0):

It might reduce latency *somewhat* if the internal network has better routing than Internet, but most of the latency likely comes from the physical distance, so a faraway VM will never feel like it's local no matter what network you reach it through.

> How would I configure two servers, Server A, and Server B, such that I connect to Server B using OpenVPN, and it forwards all the traffic to Server B?

1. Start by setting up another VPN/tunnel between the servers. It doesn't need to be the same type; you could preferably go for a static WireGuard or GRE tunnel instead of OpenVPN. (If WireGuard is used with wg-quick, specify a custom Table= option, it'll help with later configuration.)
2. Configure IP routes such that server B is able to reach your OpenVPN clients via A. (Adding a static route on B via A should be enough; A being in the middle already has routes both ways.)
3. On A, use "policy routing" so that packets *from* the OpenVPN interface (or IP range) select a different routing table, one that directs everything through the A-B tunnel instead of the regular default gateway.
4. On B, nothing special, just IP forwarding in general. Make sure your NAT (MASQUERADE) configuration is only applied on B (the border of your network), not on A.

> Would my public IP be Server A's or Server B's public IP address?

In practice, B is the most useful choice.

Technically it could also be A, but the platform will likely prevent B from originating traffic with A as source, and of course return traffic would go straight to A over Internet instead of entering GCP via B, which would defeat half the point of the exercise.